# Unit Tests are failing in TFS Visual Studio Test task but not failed running is Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

We have a project which consists of about 2000 unit tests. 
Our environment is has VS 2017 on Windows 2019 , 32 GB of memory.
We can build the project and run the unit test without any issues, again, again and again.

We build the project using TFS build task(MSBUILD) which is successful but most of the unit tests fail

The following error occurs in the log file.

> ```
> Failed   NewMenuFunctionsTest
> Error Message:
> Unable to create instance of class SetupTool.Tester.Services.ModelExtensionsTest. Error: 
> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The operation completed successfully.
> Stack Trace:
> at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.RegisterClassEx(WNDCLASSEX_D wc_d)
> at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper..ctor(Int32 classStyle, Int32 style, Int32 exStyle, Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 
> width, Int32 height, String name, IntPtr parent, HwndWrapperHook[] hooks)
> at MS.Win32.MessageOnlyHwndWrapper..ctor()
> at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher..ctor()
> at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.get_CurrentDispatcher()
> at Swf.Common.UnitTestHelper.WpfUnitTest..ctor() in 
> D:\Agent_Downloads\VB32B\_work\1\s\WPF\WPF_Common\Swf.Common.UnitTestHelper\WpfUnitTest.cs:line 97
> at SetupTool.Tester.Services.ModelExtensionsTest..ctor()
> ```

So why the project and UT pass in visual studio but fail in TFS build?
   What other information may be needed to resolve?

Is there a process to attached the log file for StackOverflow?

Joe

Comment: We had a similar problem when the solution had a mix of .net framework and .net core  unit test projects in it.  Is that your case also?

Comment: Bradley Uffner, Thank for for asking the question

Comment: Only .net framework UT's are performed in the project. Would adding the log file be of benefit?

Comment: It couldn't hurt.

Comment: I added line of log file in PasteBin - Description is VSTEST Failures

Comment: You will either need to update your question with a link to PasteBin, or add the link in a comment.

Comment: New information. Using the "vstest.console.exe" command at the "Developer Command Prompt for VS 2017" only has issue on Windows 2019.

Comment: The same vstest.console.exe command works perfectly on Win 10 and Win 2016. I copied over the DLL directory from Win 2019 to the two other servers to run the test. So does Windows 2019 have special requirements? The first 80 tests or so run successfully and fast but then the tests start hang run very slow and "OutOfMemory" messages occur for each test. The server has plenty of memory

Comment: I would point toward incorrect written tests BUT the test work perfectly and fast on Win 10 and Win 2016. These two OS run through 2000 tests in 3.3 minutes consistantly. The win 2019 unit test fail and hang after 80 tests or so.